# ruby output to file is causing unwanted line breaks

Tags: ruby

My ruby program is causing unwanted line breaks when calling a variable within a string.

The string is then printed to a text file. In this text file there are lot of unwanted line breaks.

Heres my code.

---

```
puts 'What is the 2nd Octet?'
second_octet = gets
puts 'What is the 3rd Octet?'
third_octet = gets
puts 'What is the vlan number?'
vlan_number = gets

vrf_number = <<-eos
123#{vlan_number}
eos

router_config = <<-eos 
interface Bundle-Ether7.#{vlan_number}
description * #{description_name} *
mtu 9216
vrf #{vrf_number}
ipv4 address 10.#{second_octet}.#{third_octet}.252 255.255.255.0

eos

File.open(config, 'w') { |file| file.write(router_config) }`
```

I'm getting line breaks after I call the variables so there are gaps between lines, this is extremely annoying with the second_octet and third_octet variables as it splits the ip address across multiple lines.

Any help would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string returned by `gets` includes the newline character (`\n` or `\r\n`) from the return/enter key. You need to do `gets.chomp` to take off the trailing newline, or `gets.strip` to get rid of leading and trailing whitespace. Either one should work in your case.

Comment: thanks for that, works pretty well. however, I still get a line break after where I define the vrf_number. .strip doesnt seem to work here, is there an equivalent?

Comment: If I understand your problem, you can either do `vrf_number.strip!` after you define `vrf_number` — `strip!` changes the string directly, rather than returning a new string — or change `vrf_number = <<-eos` to `vrf_number = <<-eos.strip`, which will `strip` the string before storing it in `vrf_number`.

Comment: It can be helpful to try these out in irb, so you can see the results and fine-tune until they turn out the way you want.